# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' in template files

Tags: angular

I've recently upgraded all the packages in my Angular project. But now it's erroring everywhere where I mention 'controls' in template files.
So for example it's making me change:

```
*ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.items.controls; let i=index"
```

to

```
*ngFor="let item of myForm.controls.items['controls']; let i=index"
```

Is this really necessary? Is there a way I can get the app to allow this. Seems such a small technicality.

Comment: generally you use a getter: `get itemsArray(){return this.myForm.get('items') as FormArray}` -or from Angular 12 `return this.myForm.controls.items as FormArray`, and use `*ngFor="let item of itemsArray.controls;let i=index"`.

Comment: It can also be a method in ts file like - getControls() {
  return (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('items')).controls;
} and use it as *ngFor="let ctrlof getControls(); let i = index"